# Run multiple await at the same time

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8.1-universal

I have a code that looks something like this:

```
firstList = await GetFirstListFilesAsync();
textBlock1.Text = "found " + firstList.Count + " first list's results";
secondList = await GetSecondListFilesAsync();
textBlock2.Text = "found " + secondList.Count + " second list's results";
thirdList = await GetThirdListFilesAsync();
textBlock3.Text = "found " + thirdList.Count + " third list's results"
```

So now it gets first list, sets first `TextBlock` text, then it gets second list, sets second `TextBlock` text and then gets third list and sets third `TextBlock` text. But I would like that all await operations would run simultaneously, so all `TextBlock`s would update more or less at the same time. Or maybe not at the same time - each `TextBlock` would update as the corresponding await method finishes. Anyway, what I want to achieve here, is to get results faster. if I run those methods one by one, they wait until the previous is finished, but if they would run all at the same time, third method would return the result faster, right? So my question is - is that possible? And if yes, then how?

Comment: Make a new function and put all the logic of GetFirstListFilesAsync, GetSecondListFilesAsync, GetThirdListFilesAsync and return an array or Dictionary of int and List<> and run that function with await.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var tasks = new Task<MyMethodReturnObject>[3];
tasks[0] = GetFirstListFilesAsync();
tasks[1] = GetSecondListFilesAsync();
tasks[2] = GetThirdListFilesAsync();

// At this point, all three tasks are running at the same time.

// Now, we await them all.
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// Get an individual result, where result is MyMethodReturnObject
var myText = tasks[0].Result;

// Loop through results
var results = tasks.Select(o => o.Result).ToList();
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.Write(result);
}
```

Source: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: Ok, but how can I assign results to lists using this?

Comment: My syntax may be slightly off here as I dont have access to VS right now, but something like:
`code` var results = tasks.Select(o => o.Result).ToList();
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                // Do something with result -- result.Count;
            } `code`

Comment: Very good answer @jondow . @dace just do `firstList = tasks[0].Result;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try and shift the work into a collection of `Task`s and the use [`Task.WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) to join the threads.

Comment: Or as simple as putting all the waits together then call the set text value like this :

firstList = await GetFirstListFilesAsync();
secondList = await GetSecondListFilesAsync();
thirdList = await GetThirdListFilesAsync();

textBlock1.Text = "found " + firstList.Count + " first list's results";

textBlock2.Text = "found " + secondList.Count + " second list's results";

textBlock3.Text = "found " + thirdList.Count + " third list's results"

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want to group the `await` blocks, you want to specify what happens when they complete.

```
GetFirstListFilesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
   textBlock1.Text = "found " + task.Result.Count + " first list's results";
}); 
GetSecondListFilesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
   textBlock2.Text = "found " + task.Result.Count + " second list's results";
}); 
GetThirdListFilesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
   textBlock3.Text = "found " + task.Result.Count + " third list's results";
});
```

This way will be the fastest way to do this, because as soon as the `Task` completes, your `textBlock.Text` will be set, and they will not wait on the previous one to complete.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like that all await operations would run simultaneously, so all TextBlocks would update more or less at the same time. Or maybe not at the same time - each TextBlock would update as the corresponding await method finishes.

Then define a few new methods:

```
private async Task<TFirst> GetFirstListFilesAndDisplayAsync()
{
  var firstList = await GetFirstListFilesAsync();
  textBlock1.Text = "found " + firstList.Count + " first list's results";
}

private async Task<TSecond> GetSecondListFilesAndDisplayAsync()
{
  var secondList = await GetSecondListFilesAsync();
  textBlock2.Text = "found " + secondList.Count + " second list's results";
}

private async Task<TThird> GetThirdListFilesAndDisplayAsync()
{
  var thirdList = await GetThirdListFilesAsync();
  textBlock3.Text = "found " + thirdList.Count + " third list's results";
}
```

And then call them all concurrently:

```
var firstTask = GetFirstListFilesAndDisplayAsync();
var secondTask = GetSecondListFilesAndDisplayAsync();
var thirdTask = GetThirdListFilesAndDisplayAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask, thirdTask);

firstList = await firstTask;
secondList = await secondTask;
thirdList = await thirdTask;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use david's answer or just as simple as putting all the waits together then call the set text value like this :

```
firstList = await GetFirstListFilesAsync();
secondList = await GetSecondListFilesAsync();
thirdList = await GetThirdListFilesAsync();

textBlock1.Text = "found " + firstList.Count + " first list's results";

textBlock2.Text = "found " + secondList.Count + " second list's results";

textBlock3.Text = "found " + thirdList.Count + " third list's results"
```

Comment: This still doesn't run the tasks in parallel. `GetSecondListFilesAsync` will not be called until after the awaitable that `GetFirstListFilesAsync` produces has completed.

Answer (score -1):

Just seperate the *creation* of your awaitables from the actual `await` on them:

```
var firstWait = GetFirstListFilesAsync();
var secondWait = GetSecondListFilesAsync();
var thirdWait = GetThirdListFilesAsync();
firstList = await firstWait;
textBlock1.Text = "found " + firstList.Count + " first list's results";
secondList = await secondWait ;
textBlock2.Text = "found " + secondList.Count + " second list's results";
thirdList = await thirdWait ;
textBlock3.Text = "found " + thirdList.Count + " third list's results";
```

This still won't *show* any results until the first item has completed, but does allow progress to be made in parallel. It's more complex if you do want to deal with each one *as* it completes inside a single function, since you then have to `WaitAny` on the collection of awaitables, then determine (manually) which one(s) have completed, remove those from the collection and loop around until all have finished.