# Asynchronous Run Action Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I use Asp.Net Core 2 and find some "bug" or may be not.

I have some action methods like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index() {
    for (int k = 0; k < int.MaxValue / 2; k++) { await Task.Delay(0); }
    return View();
}
```

OR

```
public IActionResult Index() {
    for (int k = 0; k < int.MaxValue; k++) {  }
    return View();
}
```

All of this do delay equals 5 seconds.

If I run 5 tab at the same time (together) in browser last tab executed for 25 second. Because, it wating previous tabs.

I write this code on ASP.NET MVC 4, and 5 tabs executed for 5.5 seconds, NOT 25!!!

I can't believe it. And can't resolve it.

Why actions in ASP.NET Core 2 run synchronously? What is wrong?
How I understanding on request from browser ASP.NET Core 2 must create a new instance of controller , initialized it and execute the method, is it true?
May be I configured the project wrong? Where I can change this option?

Comment: Because you're awaiting each async method and then calling the next one and then waiting, etc. Assign the tasks to variables and await after setting them all off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run multiple await at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907549/run-multiple-await-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @john His issue is that running his code five times by launching five different tabs does not parallelise. It seems unlikely that changing how he awaits within one run of his code will affect that.

Comment: @Rawling, yes this is my problem(( it's not depended from awaiting into actions. You are right.

Comment: What is the exact action which causes it? I mean you don't actually use code posted in your question I guess, so what's the real code?

Comment: @Evk, my code is default created by template for web project by VS 2017. At first I found this issue in my real project, but then I create a new simple and try it, and I found my issue again in new simple project

Comment: I search any suggestions here how to resolve this issue

Comment: @Rawling I think I must have misunderstood what he was asking.

Comment: @RomanReaLD If you expect 5 tabs to run asynchronously, I think you need to show us how you're making your ajax calls.

Comment: @john, it's not ajax call, it's simple get requests, and they are working in ASP.NET MVC 4, but not here

Comment: Oh, you mean multiple browser tabs, not multiple tabs in a web application?

Comment: Yes, multiple browser tabs and they are syncronous

Comment: I have tried to reproduce and it looked like the first few requests were synchronous but subsequent requests were asynchronous. Can you confirm?

Comment: @john, yes, I was watching this behavior, but it seems very strange. I don't understand how it working... and when it is parallel and when not( may be exist some way to resolve it

Comment: Where do you host your server (IIS, IIS Express, nginx, self-hosted maybe)? Which browser you use for test?

Comment: @Evk, IIS Express from VS and a have tried deploing on IIS, Chrome and IE behaviors as same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is most likely not related to asp.net core or web server in general, but to how browsers handle concurrent requests to the same url. I cannot tell for all browsers, so will use only Chrome as an example.

You open 5 pages in chrome, all pointing to the same url of your server. Handling this request by server takes 5 seconds. Chrome will *not* issue all 5 requests concurrently by default. Instead it will issue only 1, because it thinks that it might be able to cache response and reuse it for other 4 requests. When first response arrives it sees that unfortunately it cannot reuse it (because you don't provide any cache headers). In then issues second request with the same hope, and so on. In result, all 5 requests are issued one by one, in the hope that response might be reused for subsequent request.

So it's not asp.net which handles requests sequentially - it's web browser which does that.

If you add some headers that allow browser to cache response, for example:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 30)]
public IActionResult Index() {

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return Ok("test");
}
```

Then it will again issue just 1 request and after response arrives (5 seconds) it will see that indeed response can be reused. Then other 4 pending requests will be resolved immediately (from cache).

Or if you say browser that it should not store cache for this request:

```
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]
public IActionResult Index() {

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return Ok("test");
}
```

It will issue 1 request and after getting response it realizes that there is no hope to reuse response for subsequent requests (because response header forbids storing cache). Then it will issue pending 4 requests concurrently.

Of course you should not use cache headers mentioned above just to avoid this behavior - they were just for example to confirm the behavior.

In general you should not worry about this. It's unlikely that someone will open your website 5 times in the same browser, and even if they do - it's unlikely long waiting in such scenario is a big problem. However if somehow your application is designed to be used like that - you might indeed use cache headers to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks very much for so detailed description, but I'm worried about why in the ASP.NET MVC 4 (for example ) this issue doesn't exist?

Comment: @RomanReaLD you need to check which response headers your MVC 4 version sends (with fiddler or browser dev tools). It's possible that it sets some of the cache headers mentioned.

Comment: thanks a lot, I checked one url in 3 browser - it's realy async.

Comment: I will try later ASP.NET MVC 4 to check this issue. And thanks again!!!

Comment: @RomanReaLD would be good if you can comment here about the results of your MVC 4 check after you do it.